# Biblatex-Angew. Chem.; Angew. Chem. Int. Ed

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chem

I have a problem with the biblatex-chem bundle by @Joseph Wright. My problem concerns the citatation of the journal Angew. Chem. and Angew. Chem. Int. Ed. . If I use the command `\cite{Name}` with a related Journal for the International Edition both Journals are listed, while the International Edition is listed after the Angew. Chem. Edition and separated by semicolon like should be. But when I have a second journal which should be listed as a subentry, the Angew. Chem. Int. Ed. entry always disappears in the bibliography.

So here `\cite{Ache1989}` works. If I use `\mcite{set1,*Ache1989,*Wurm.2017}` (both Journals are linked to their Internation Edition) they appear as Entry a) and b) but without the Int. Ed.

How can I make it work?

Thank you

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,captions=nooneline]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[style=chem-angew,mcite=true,backend=biber,chaptertitle,pageranges=true,subentry]{biblatex}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{references = {Literatur}}
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}
\let\cite=\supercite

\begin{document}
\newpage
\cite{Ache1989}
\cite{Wurm.2017}
\newpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Bibfile:

```
 @article{Wurm.2017,
 author = {Wurm, Thomas and Bucher, Janina and Duckworth, Sarah B. and Rudolph, Matthias and Rominger, Frank and Hashmi, A. Stephen K.},
 year = {2017},
 pages = {3413--3417},
 pagination = {page},
 volume = {129},
 number = {12},
 journal = {Angew. Chem.},
 doi = {10.1002/ange.201700057},
 related     = {Wurm.2017c},
 relatedtype = {translatedas},
 }

 @article{Wurm.2017c,
 author = {Wurm, Thomas and Bucher, Janina and Duckworth, Sarah B. and Rudolph, Matthias and Rominger, Frank and Hashmi, A. Stephen K.},
year = {2017},

 pages = {3364--3368},
 pagination = {page},
 volume = {56},
 number = {12},
 journal = {Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.},
 doi = {10.1002/anie.201700057},
}


@ARTICLE{Ache1989,
  author = {H. J. Ache},
  journal = {Angew. Chem},
  year = {1989},
  volume = {101},
  pages = {1-21},
  related     = {Ache1989a},
  relatedtype = {translatedas},
}

@ARTICLE{Ache1989a,
  author = {H. J. Ache},
  journal = {Angew. Chem. Int. Ed.},
  year = {1989},
  volume = {28},
  pages = {1-20},
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Interesting problem. A work-around is `\mcite{set1,*Ache1989,*Wurm.2017}\nocite{Ache1989,Wurm.2017}`.

Comment: If you want to you can try the development version of Biber (2.8 dev) as well as `biblatex` 3.8. With those versions your MWE should work with `\mcite{set1,*Ache1989,*Wurm.2017}` alone.

Answer (score 1):

The whole set mechanism is currently being worked on. See [issue #470](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/470). With the upcoming version 2.8 of Biber and `biblatex` 3.8 things should work as expected. The problem was that `related` entries of `@set` items were not processed in the same way that `related` entries of `\cite`'d or `\nocite`'d entries were. This has now been addressed.

For the time being a `\nocite{Ache1989,Wurm.2017}` of the involved parents is enough as a work-around.

```
\mcite{set1,*Ache1989,*Wurm.2017}\nocite{Ache1989,Wurm.2017}
```